# return both a file and a rendered view in an MVC3 Controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, download

is it possible to both return a file for download and update a view from a controller method call?

or a workaround is needed, maybe using javascript (calling a refresh of the page after loading)?

the file download is created on the fly along the parameters set in a ViewModel
(search parameters from various controls on the page).

Comment: No, you are going to have to find another way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can return the address of file using ViewModel or ViewData from your action, and use `window.location.href` as demonstrated in the following code at the end of your view.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    /* ... */

    ViewBag.FileName = "{FileName}";
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Download(string id) {
    /* ... */

    return File("{Path}", "{MIME type}", "{Desired file name}");
}
```

**Markup**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.location.href = "/home/download/" + "@Ajax.JavaScriptStringEncode(@ViewBag.FileName)";

</script>
```

Comment: what if my file isn't stored phisically, but a stream whose content depends on series of form controls?

Comment: @AlessandroLendaro The `FileResult` has an overload for you that gets stream instead of path. Also, you can send your values from client to server via querystring or route parameter.

Answer (score 2):

While it is not possible to return a FileResult alongside a ViewResult, you could use a meta refresh on the returned view to redirect to the file once the page loads.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600;url=/path/to/the/file" />
```

Answer (score 1):

One request can have one response who's response type is defined in the response header so the basic answer is no.
What you could look at doing is returning a view which contains javascript which will then request the file download.