# return a View and File in a single method in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am building an app in ASP.Net MVC, and want to return a `View` AND offer a download to the user. Is it possible? Right now, I can return a new page using

```
return View();
```

offer a file download using:

```
return File(FilePath, "text", "downloadFileName");
```

reason for this: There will be a checkbox indicating "if download file". If checked, upon the click of a button the specified content will be displayed on the screen and a download dialog will appear.

Any help is appreciated!

UPDATE:
In the end, I chose to provide a download link in the returned `View`, which works well for the app now.

Comment: The only way I can think to do that would be to return the view, with some javascript that automatically navigates to the file. Most browsers when navigating to a file download, will not actually change the page, they will just prompt for file download.

Comment: See this SO question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081095/return-both-a-file-and-a-rendered-view-in-an-mvc3-controller-action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use like below.

```
ViewData["text"] = "text that you need to return";
ViewData["FileName"] = "Name of the file that you need to return";
ViewData["Filepath"] = "Path of the file that you need to return";

return View();
```

In your view you can use them like below

```
@{
    var text = ViewData["text"];
    var filename = ViewData["FileName"];
    var filePath = ViewData["Filepath"];
}
```

If you need to done without using ViewData or ViewBage  means please follow the below code.

There are 3 steps need to do for it.

Step 1:
  Create a model class for it.
My model code

```
public class FileDetails
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public string Filepath { get; set; }
}
```

Step 2: Controller code to return view with FileDetails Model.

```
FileDetails Details = new FileDetails();
Details.Text = "text that you need to return";
Details.FileName = "Name of the file that you need to return";
Details.Filepath = "Path of the file that you need to return";
return View("ViewName", Details);
```

Step 3: Your View must contain the FileDetails model Header. like Below

```
@model YourProjectName.Models.FileDetails
```

The above code is must be at top of your view page where you need to use those details.

My View code

```
@{
    var text = Model.Text;
    var filename = Model.FileName;
    var filePath = Model.Filepath;
}
```

Comment: thanks! guess it's not possible to return a View and Download simultaneously, offering a download link is the next thing.

Comment: It is possible if you can use a model for it. can i update that code for you?

Comment: sure. but, would it be simpler to just show it in your post?

Comment: Sure. Please wait for 2 mins.

Comment: Please see my updated code this will helps you to get what you want. make sure your fileDetails Model is placed under the Models folder in your application

Comment: thanks for the update. this still only shows the filepath (or possibily a download link) in the View, not the same as returning a Download, right? (does not show a download dialog offering the user to save a file.)

Comment: That you can done by javascript at the time of loading the view file.

Comment: sorry i am new to javascript. would you give me some pointers in achieving this using js? thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the late, went for lunch. Let me know your code that you used to download the file  and where you downloading it, from the local machine or from the server ?

Comment: actually never mind; I just provide a download link, which might actually be more appropriate for the app at the time. I'll spend more time learning js meanwhile. thanks again :)