# Render view and download file in the same request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When a user has completed a form the user is redirected to the thank you page. The thank you page shall render it's view, but also download a file (pdf / a stream).

I would prefer to do this without using javascript like this
[return both a file and a rendered view in an MVC3 Controller action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081095/return-both-a-file-and-a-rendered-view-in-an-mvc3-controller-action) and I would prefer to get the Save As dialog.

Has MVC any conventions that can handle this?

Comment: You can't return 2 responses to the browser. The best you can do is trigger a second request from the view as per the linked answer.

Comment: Any specific reason a button on the page to download is not suitable. As Personally i would only associate this sort of action with dodgy websites

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @BenRobinson pointed out, you can't return two responses from a single request. No, MVC doesn't have any conventions to handle this because it's a fundamental limitation of the platform you're developing on, the Internet, and specifically the TCP/IP and HTTP protocols.

Fundamentally, the web revolves around what's called the request-response cycle. A client (usually a web browser) issues a request to a server, and that server responds with the requested resource. What you're talking about would be akin to request-response-response, which is not possible. The server cannot just up and send a response to a client without first receiving a request.

As a result, your options are:

1. Use JavaScript to programmatically issue another request, such as by setting `location.href` as the accepted answer on your linked question suggests.
2. Provide a link/button/whatever to allow the user to initiate a request for the file manually.

That's it. Either way, you need a new request, either initiated by JavaScript or the end user to get the file.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried meta refresh Trick.

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV='REFRESH' CONTENT='5;URL=http://www.example.com/test.txt'>
```

Remember to set the header `Content-Disposition: attachment` for the file that you want to download in browser.

Comment: Nice catch. I always forget about meta refresh as it's so "90's"; it left my brain about the same time as the blink tag. Anways, yep, that would be a perfectly valid third option, and again, another way of issuing a second request, which is necessary to get your second response.

Comment: I am still use this tag for do so many thing. work awesome even nowadays.